# How to grant a privilege to a specific container/pdb

Tags: database, oracle, database-administration, oracle19c

I have 4 pdbs in a container, however i want to grant rights to a specific pdb. Can somebody help with this situation?

Comment: This is off-topic, but what 'rights'? If you want a user to only access one PDB then create the user within that, not as a common user.

Comment: @AlexPoole, Is there a way to do that with common users? I need to find a solution for that